# typescript 1.5 language specifications

Tags: typescript

Where can i find the **typescript 1.5 language specifications** ?
[This Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf) is for the **1.4** version.
Even a draft or a working version of **1.5** language specification is OK,

Since so much have changed in the new version of typescript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always grab the appropriate language specification from the GitHub branch you are interested in:

TypeScript 1.5 Language Specification

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/release-1.5/doc

Just use the "Switch Branch" feature and you can view any version you like.

Comment: Just to complement the answer, there was a little issue updating the spec document that was addressed through a [report](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3948) in the Github repository. Hit refresh and you should see the document for the current version,1.5.